# Java - Jackson, De-Serializing subclasses

Tags: java, json, jackson

Lets assume I have the following JPA entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseForumPersistable {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String title;
    Date creationDate;
    @ManyToOne
    User user;

    //getters, setter
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class ThematicArea() {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="thematicArea")
    List<Topic> topics;

    //getters, setters
}
```

---

```
public class Topic() {

    String status;
    boolean isSticky;

    @ManyToOne
    ThematicArea thematicArea;

    @OneToMany
    List<Post> posts

    //getters, setters

}
```

I also use these entities for my `REST` Controllers that handle `POST` requests. So for instance for `Topic` I have an `/api/topics` endpoint. When I send something like this as a JSON object

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 3,
    "role": "Admin"
  },
  "thematicArea": {
    "id": 1
  },
  "title": "asdf",
  "status": "Active"
}
```

It fails to create the Thematic Area, although it perfectly creates the User entity. The controller signature is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody final Topic entity)
```

So when I use the debugger with a breakpoint, the `ThematicArea` entity is not even de-serialized.

Moreover if I send an object like this:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 3,
    "role": "Admin"
  },
  "thematicArea": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "topic_title"
  },
  "title": "asdf",
  "status": "Active"
}
```

Which now also includes a `title` field in the `ThematicArea` object the two title fields get mixed up. This leads me to believe that it's an issue of de-serializing. Any ideas how i can fix this.